# Is it possible to create a test repository for mockMVC?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, mocking, mockmvc

I have the test below:

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest
public class ProjectDashboardTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void projectsDashboardShows() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc
                .perform(get("/projects/1"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    public void projectFormShows() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc
                .perform(get("/get-project-form/1"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
```

These rely upon path variables 1 = user ID. For these tests to work correctly there must a user account with user id = 1 which is currently logged in. How would I simulate that in mockMVC?

Comment: You don't _simulate_ it; the precondition of that test is that the project exists ("given that a project with the ID 1 exists in the database"), so create it in the DB, either through the API or using the relevant repository.

Comment: @jonrsharpe So within each test I would need to add the project to the database? I am using h2 database so I cannot persist data as the tests must pass on a build. Thanks.

Comment: In (or _before_) each test that needs a project to have been created you need to create a project, yes.

Comment: Thanks, so I could create a project in the test class local scope as opposed to within the test methods?

Comment: You should use method with `@BeforeEach` from JUnit5 for example.

Answer (score 0):

You have few options, depends which test you want to create and which configuration you have (more detail is needed to answer more accurately).

For unit tests, you can mock your repository (or service), and method in which you get the `Project`. For example if you have `ProjectService` with method `getProjectById(Long id)`, you can use something like that:

```java
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest
public class ProjectDashboardTests {
    ...
    @MockBean
    private ProjectService service; // <- mock your service

    @Test
    public void projectsDashboardShows() throws Exception {
        // mock service method in selected test or in @BeforeEach method
        Mockito.when(service.getProjectById(ArgumentMatchers.anyLong())
                .thenReturn(new Project(/* your own test object*/)); 
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Based on *For these tests to work correctly there must a user account with user id = 1 which is currently logged in*, I assume you work with Spring Security? You can take a look at the [`@WithMockUser`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/test/context/support/WithMockUser.html) annotation if you want simulate selected user.

For integration tests, you should prepare database (H2 for example) for tests only, before **each** test add project into db and remove after **each** test (run independently).